# Can KNN theoretically be less accurate than pattern averaging?

Tags: pattern-recognition, k-nearest-neighbour

My task is pattern recognition. I need to classify 2D matrices into an arbitrary number of classes.

The question is: For pattern classification, could k nearest neighbours algorithm ever be less accurate that simple pattern averaging.

To illustrate what I mean by pattern averaging:

Let's assume the patterns are 2D binary matrices. Let's also assume there are 4 patterns in total.
$\bigl(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\bigr)$

We can now split them into two categories: has 1's only in the first column and has 1's only in the second column. And the pattern averages for the two classes become:

$\bigl(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0.5 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0.5\\
0 & 0.5\\
\end{bmatrix}
\bigr)$

To determine which class a pattern belongs to, we would take simple Euclidean distance.

I'm wondering if the above method could ever be more accurate that knn.

[This question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067896/can-knn-theoretically-be-less-accurate-than-pattern-averaging), but it is closer in nature to machine learning that mathematics]